# How to create hover error messages in Ace code editor

Tags: jquery, html, css, ace-editor

I am using an Ace editor to display code on a website. I would like to be able to highlight ranges of code and display an error message when they are hovered over, as shown in the picture.

[image: What I would like to accomplish]

I'm not sure if this can be done using the Ace editor API, or if I need to use the magic of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't ready to use api for this.

Tooltip can be added similar to [token_tooltip](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/demo/kitchen-sink/token_tooltip.js) in ace, but it needs some reworking, to add an arrow and not move with the mouse.